# Old version of page is loaded after clearing cache

Tags: html, caching, webserver

I have a really weird issue that I can't really get my head around. I updated a website to have a responsive design. I deleted the old css files and created new ones. But the browser keeps loading the old pages.

I did delete the cache and all that, even tried it on browsers I never visited the site with, but it keeps showing the old page.

That being said it is actually even weirder. When I click around a bit the correct files are loaded, but as soon as I try it in another browser or a private window or I delete all website data it starts showing the files again, which shouldn't even exist anymore.

Any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: What you can try is adding a variable (v=1) after the css declaration. For example: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mycss.css?v=1">

Comment: How are you clearing the cache? `Ctrl`+`F5`? Have you used the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and looked into the Inspector, which version of the page was loaded? Or looked into the Network tab, whether the page was loaded from cache?

Comment: @Gerard It is actually the index.html that is not being loaded correctly, so updating the tag won't do anything I'm afraid.

Comment: @Xufox: I tried everything, ctrl+F5, going into the settings, putting a ?var=test at the end of the address. Private windows and even newly downloaded browsers and browsers on other computers that haven't ever visited the webpage. The network cache shows the data being loaded after clearing the cache. Just the wrong data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say *"I did delete the cache"* do you mean the browser cache? Have you tried to delete the files in the cache folder of your website (if there is such folder) or are you using a builder like Joomla or similar? These systems use to have own cache mechanics that can be deleted in the admin panel. I had these issues in the past after bigger updates and the solution was to delete the server side cache from folders or via the admin panel of the system I had used.

Comment: I think you might be on the right track here. Unfortuntley I am not the website owner or the one who originally created the website. I just implemented the responsive design and therefor only have an ftp access right now and I couldn't find a cache folder there. I contacted the page admin but they are busy because of christmas right now, so I figured it wouldn't hurt to ask for any other ideas. But I agree that it seems most likely to be a server issue.

Comment: In some systems you can choose the cache folder. Maybe it just has another name than “cache”. Spontaneous idea ;)

Comment: Just because you don't have enough reputation to comment does not mean you should add an answer that does not answer the question (though IMO this question is too vague and should be closed anyway). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead) *Can I put my comment in an answer? - **No***.

Comment: OK, I guess I got this now. I'm reading these "how-to's" now and then but I think I just didn't see this one, yet. Sorry for this. The thread shows that comments being saved as answers should be removed. So since the asker has seen it... my answer can be removed and my learning status has increased. Thanks for the links.

Comment: This is a valid answer and not commentary it could well be a caching problem and your correct in your answer could you please remove the I don't have enough reputation comment at the start of this answer.

Comment: That's nice, @Martin, this might be a correct answer but your previous speakers are also right. I did something that's not correct. If there's a situation now where some want to reprimand me and some want this to be a "real" answer I will just let this up to the higher privileged ones to edit my answer or remove ist. If I edit it, some might get upset, if I don't edit it, some might get upset because the answer could be correct. Decide yourself - I will accept what's going to happen.

Comment: I was speaking as a user moderator with that the Answer is a valid one and not just commentary, I think your drawing more negative view on this by that comment at the top, if that was not there, I would not have assumed this was commentary and was a valid answer. It could do with some formatting but other than that if this was my question that would be a perfectly valid answer an explained "check this caching due to this".

Comment: Well then... I've edited the answer. Time for holidays for all of us :D

Comment: I considered that (and @Martin is right adding that at the top is just drawing a bullseye on your back). My issue here is, this answer is mostly questions. This implies to me that your trying to clarify the question, not answer it. Like I said, this is a poor question which isn't helping.

Comment: So I should have written "Try to delete [...]." instead of "Have you tried to delete [...]?" - if I got you right. I think you're right then.

Comment: So some time down the road the page is working perfectly fine, without doing anything else. So I guess it was a server side cache problem. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You're welcome. First "best answer" so thank you, too :D